# How to do the loop and calculate a function when ranges of values are different and from different types?

Tags: python, string, numpy, dictionary, python-itertools

I have a function which gets two elements one of them is a string, another one is a list of integers, and I want my function to get these values and calculate it, so far I did this:

```
number_of_people = list(range(10))
color_of_eyes=['green','blue']
for i, j in list(itertools.product(number_of_people , color_of_eyes)):
    pop = number_of_people [i]
    eyes=color_of_eyes[j]
    myfunc=Interest(population=pop, eye_color=eyes)
```

if I do this, I get: **list indices must be integers or slices, not str** for `number_of_people [i]`

I don't know if `itertools.product` do what I want correctly: basically, I want my function to calculate this: the first one (`number_of_people=1`) to be blue, first one again to be green this time, second one with `'blue'`, second one with `'green'`, ... and so on. (so it will be `20` values in total/)

PS: I would like to do this with `map` but I am not sure how:
I know this is wrong again to write is as following but how is the correct way of doing it?

```
for i in range(len(number_of_people):
    for j in range (len(color_of_eyes)):
       map(lambda number_of_people[i], 
        color_of_eyes[j]:Interest(population=number_of_people[i], 
        eye_color=color_of_eyes[j])
```

Comment: You may be doing too much work for yourself. You combine the lists with `product`, then you try to go back to the initial lists to...index into them? You can't index into a list with `list['green']`, it would have to be `color_of_eyes[color_of_eyes.index(j)]`, which is a tautology. I'm not clear on what `Interest()` is doing, but shouldn't you just eliminate the `pop=` and `eyes=` steps, and just call `Interest(i, j)`?

Comment: `i` and `j` are not indices but are the actual values. I agree with @G.Anderson, you can use them directly

Comment: @g.anderson  oh thank you!  but if I want to go through a loop with my string and in the loop I should replace those strings to get the value of my function how should I do it?

Comment: @loginn thanks a lot I got the mistake now.

Comment: Removing the lines with `pop=` and `eyes=` and changing the last line to `myfunc=Interest(population=i, eye_color=j)` is what I _think_ you're trying to get at